# Условие внутри события Android

Tags: android, java

```
public class ZastavkaActive extends Activity {
    ImageButton imageButton;
    private static final String MY_SETTINGS = "my_settings";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zastavka);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    /*Имагебаттон на весь экран в виде картинки, при нажатии на нее происходит проверка
    в первый ли раз запускается приложение. Если в первый, то мы переходим на активити с выбором города,
     а если не в первый, то идем прямо в эфир   
    */

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zastavkabutton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MY_SETTINGS,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);

                if (!hasVisited) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ZastavkaActive.this,
                            SelectCityActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Editor e = sp.edit();
                    e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
                    e.commit(); // подтверждаем изменения
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ZastavkaActive.this, EfirActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ребята, вопрос в следующем. Есть `imagebutton` и есть событие которое его обрабатывает. Внутри обработки события, присутствует условие которое проверяет в первый ли раз программа запущена на устройстве или нет. Делается это за счет проверки созданной настройки, то есть если этой настройки нет, то значит приложение запускается впервые, если она есть то невпервые. И уже от сюда идут разные действия: если впервые, то запускается активность `SelectCityActivity`, а если не впервые то запускается активность `EfirActivity`. Вот только проблема вот в чем. При запуске впервые все проходит отлично, а именно появляется эта `imagebutton` которая находиться на `ZastavkaActive`, мы на нее жмем и попадаем в `SelectCityActivity`, при этом у нас создается запись в настройку, о том что, приложение уже запускалось. Если приложение запускается повторно на устройстве, то почему то сразу запускается `EfirActivity`, а сначала должна запуститься `ZastavkaActive` и только после нажатия на `imagebutton` должно появиться `EfirActivity`. Почему так происходит? Почему при повторном запуске появляется сразу `EfirActivity` минуя `ZastavkaActive`?

Comment: ну ты логи поставь, подебаж, возможно оно просто быстро пролитает изза условия, настройка true - запускается ЭфмрАктивити

Comment: нужно выложить другой исходный код, так как этот код, как вы говорите, не вызывается при "не первом" запуске программы.

Comment: а если после того, как свернули программу, зайти в настройки и сделать остановку программе, то все нормально снова заработает, да?

Comment: что то мне кажется, косяк  с состояниями.